# Multiple domain redirection to different domain from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have different urls as

1) http://$$$.com/ABC/
Which should redirect to http://$$$.$$$.com/ABC/

2) http://www.$$$.eu/ABC/
Which should redirect to  http://www.$$$.com/ABC/

How can I make htaccess conditions and rewrite rule in htaccess. Please help

Comment: What is "$$$.$$$" meant to express? Twice the exact same word?

Comment: No they are different

Comment: So it looks like you need to add some more explanation details what you actually want to achieve, right?